# COUNTIF formula + reference + array

Tags: google-sheets

Here's a [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j8IVZAvUINIPfhtJygHSD9ZA2JizytOwEuP1h_tvqo8/edit#gid=258610801) of the Google Sheets I'm working on and here's what I'm trying to do:

I need a COUNTIF formula that would count as `1` if the sum from columns R to AD in the `Failed` sheet is less than `8`. There are five potential responses to columns R to AD and each is assigned a weight:

```
0 - Not at all  
1 - To a slight degree 
2 - To a moderate degree 
3 - To a great degree 
4 - All the time
```

Based on the current data, row 30 in the `Reports` sheet should count as `2`.

But how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. I'll try that. But I've also come up with another formula (please see the spreadsheet) although it's quite lengthy. Would be great if you could show me a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the correct countif formula is in your reports sheet right now - but in answer to your comment - if you want to simplify that huge if statement, you can use arrayformula, and vlookup or substitute to trim the formula to this:

```
=if(istext(B2), SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(R2:AD2,{"Not at all",0;"To a slight degree",1;"To a moderate degree",2;"To a great degree",3;"All the time",4},2,FALSE))),)
```

for my example i gave it a short lookup table, but i included it as a literal array so that you dont have to create a helper column

[image]

or

[image]